# Overlapping problem in graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{animate} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\usepackage[paperheight=20.2cm,paperwidth=16.2cm,bottom=-1cm,top=-1cm,left=-1.8cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {31,91,...,391}{%
\draw  (\x:3cm) circle (5pt)[fill=black];
\draw  (\x:5cm) circle (5pt)[fill=black];
\draw  (\x:3cm) [line width=1pt]--  (\x+60:3cm);
\draw  (\x:3cm) [line width=1pt]--  (\x+120:3cm);
\draw  (\x:3cm) [line width=1pt]--  (\x+180:3cm);
\draw (\x:5cm) [line width=1pt]--  (\x-60:3cm);
\draw (\x:5cm) [line width=1pt]--  (\x+60:3cm);
\draw (\x:5cm) [line width=1pt]--  (\x-120:3cm);
\draw (\x:5cm) [line width=1pt]--  (\x+120:3cm);
\draw (\x:5cm)[line width=1pt]..controls(\x+120:11cm)..(\x+180:3cm);
%\draw  (\x:3cm) [line width=3pt] -- (\x+144:3cm);
%\draw  (\x:3cm) [line width=3pt] -- (\x:3cm);}
\draw(31:3cm)node[right=2pt]{\huge $v_6$};
\draw(91:3cm)node[above=2pt]{\huge $v_1$};
\draw(151:3cm)node[left=2pt]{\huge $v_2$};
\draw(211:3cm)node[left=2pt]{\huge $v_3$};
\draw(271:3cm)node[below=2pt]{\huge $v_4$};
\draw(331:3cm)node[right=2pt]{\huge $v_5$};
\draw(271:5cm)node[below=3.5cm]{\huge $S'(K_6)$};
\draw(31:5cm)node[right=2pt]{\huge $v_6'$};
\draw(91:5cm)node[above=2pt]{\huge $v_1'$};
\draw(151:5cm)node[left=2pt]{\huge $v_2'$};
\draw(211:5cm)node[left=2pt]{\huge $v_3'$};
\draw(271:5cm)node[below=2pt]{\huge $v_4'$};
\draw(331:5cm)node[right=2pt]{\huge $v_5'$};
\end{tikzpicture}     
\end{document}
```

I am drawing the above graph, in which inner labels overlapped with edges. If somebody can draw with overlapping or if some one can draw the same graph in different way it would be also helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is an error in your code: you have commented out the brace terminating the body of the `foreach` loop.

Regarding your layout problem: Use `controls` with two points.

```
\draw (A) .. controls (a) and (b) .. (B);
```

The line will leave `(A)` towards `(a)` and will approach `(B)` from the direction of `(b)`.

In your application consider replacing

```
\draw (\x:5cm)[line width=1pt]..controls(\x+120:11cm)..(\x+180:3cm);
```

by

```
\draw (\x:5cm)[line width=1pt]..controls(\x+100:10cm) and (\x+120:11cm)..(\x+180:3cm);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{animate} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\usepackage[paperheight=20.2cm,paperwidth=16.2cm,bottom=-1cm,top=-1cm,left=-1.8cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {31,91,...,391}{%
\draw  (\x:3cm) circle (5pt)[fill=black];
\draw  (\x:5cm) circle (5pt)[fill=black];
\draw  (\x:3cm) [line width=1pt]--  (\x+60:3cm);
\draw  (\x:3cm) [line width=1pt]--  (\x+120:3cm);
\draw  (\x:3cm) [line width=1pt]--  (\x+180:3cm);
\draw (\x:5cm) [line width=1pt]--  (\x-60:3cm);
\draw (\x:5cm) [line width=1pt]--  (\x+60:3cm);
\draw (\x:5cm) [line width=1pt]--  (\x-120:3cm);
\draw (\x:5cm) [line width=1pt]--  (\x+120:3cm);
%\draw (\x:5cm)[line width=1pt]..controls(\x+120:11cm)..(\x+180:3cm);
\draw (\x:5cm)[line width=1pt]..controls(\x+100:10cm) and (\x+120:11cm)..(\x+180:3cm);

%\draw  (\x:3cm) [line width=3pt] -- (\x+144:3cm);
%\draw  (\x:3cm) [line width=3pt] -- (\x:3cm);
}
\draw(31:3cm)node[right=2pt]{\huge $v_6$};
\draw(91:3cm)node[above=2pt]{\huge $v_1$};
\draw(151:3cm)node[left=2pt]{\huge $v_2$};
\draw(211:3cm)node[left=2pt]{\huge $v_3$};
\draw(271:3cm)node[below=2pt]{\huge $v_4$};
\draw(331:3cm)node[right=2pt]{\huge $v_5$};
\draw(271:5cm)node[below=3.5cm]{\huge $S'(K_6)$};
\draw(31:5cm)node[right=2pt]{\huge $v_6'$};
\draw(91:5cm)node[above=2pt]{\huge $v_1'$};
\draw(151:5cm)node[left=2pt]{\huge $v_2'$};
\draw(211:5cm)node[left=2pt]{\huge $v_3'$};
\draw(271:5cm)node[below=2pt]{\huge $v_4'$};
\draw(331:5cm)node[right=2pt]{\huge $v_5'$};
\end{tikzpicture}     
\end{document}
```